# How to reference `android:colorBackground` in XML using Material Components

Tags: android, android-theme, material-components-android, android-attributes

I have an app with several skins. In one skin i define `android:colorBackground` and then I want to set this color in an XML layout as ViewGroup background color. How do I do it? Is it possible? Or it is some attribute used by the system only?

```
<style name="SkinDefault" parent="@style/_SkinXYZ">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/skin_default_color_background</item>
    <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/skin_default_color_on_background</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 25):

Ran into this problem myself, `colorOnBackground` and the other Material Components colors can be referenced with `?attr/colorOnBackground`.
But in order to reference `android:colorBackground` you will have to preface with android like this `?android:attr/colorBackground`

Answer (score 0):

this also worked for me

```
android:textColor="?attr/android:colorBackground"
```